# Group by hash in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

My goal is to take a hash of names and numbers, for example:

```
hash = {
  "Matt" => 30,
  "Dave" => 50,
  "Alex" => 60
}
```

and to group them by whether they achieved a "passing" score. I'd like the results to be passed as an array into two separate keys, say `:pass` and `:fail` like this:

```
hash = { "pass" => ["Alex", 60], "fail" => [["Matt", 30]["Dave",60]]}
```

I know the `group_by` method is what I need, but am not sure as to how I would pass the values into the new keys.

The passing grade should be decided by the user.  For this example, you could use 45.

Comment: 1. What is the logic that makes `"Dave"`'s score `60`?

Comment: 2. What is the "passing score"?

Comment: 3. What is the logic that makes `"Alex"` (with 60) pass while `"Dave"` (somehow with 60) fail?

Comment: 4. Your `hash` does not have the keys `:pass` and `:fail`, is has `"pass"` and `"fail"`.

Comment: @sawa I appreciate the input, my example was not the greatest -- I was only using arbitrary numbers

Comment: Why the rush to select an answer?

Comment: You still need to state the passing grade for your example and change the symbols to strings in `"two separate keys, say :pass and :fail"`. You can drop the last line. That's obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do somthing this in such way:

```
PASSING_GRADE = 45
hash.group_by {|_, v| v >= PASSING_GRADE ? 'pass' : 'fail'}
```

Here is result:

```
{"fail"=>[["Matt", 30], "pass"=>[["Alex", 60], ["Dave", 50]]]}
```

Comment: This is so helpful.  I was faltering because I was not familiar with the ":pass : :fail" portion of the syntax

Comment: Yo can use "if" if you want but I think it's better to use ternary operator here

Answer (score 1):

You could simply do something like this:

```
sorted = {"pass" => [], "fail" => []}
hash.each do |name, grade|
  if grade >= PASSING_GRADE
    sorted["pass"] << [name, grade]
  else
    sorted["fail"] << [name, grade]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

**#1**

```
a = hash.to_a 
{ "pass" => a.select { |_,v| v > 50 }, "fail" => a.reject { |_,v| v > 50 } }
  #=> {"pass"=>[["Alex", 60]], "fail"=>[["Matt", 30], ["Dave", 50]]}
```

**#2**

```
[:pass, :fail].zip(hash.to_a.partition { |_,v| v > 50 }).to_h
  #=> {:pass=>[["Alex", 60]], :fail=>[["Matt", 30], ["Dave", 50]]}
```

These both give the return values as arrays of tuples, which you wanted for `"fail"` but not for `"pass"`. Wouldn't that make it a pain to work with? Is it not better for both to be arrays of tuples?

Consider returning hashes for values:

```
 {"pass" => hash.select { |_,v| v > 50 }, "fail" => hash.reject {|_,v| v > 50 }}
   #=> {"pass"=>{"Alex"=>60}, "fail"=>{"Matt"=>30, "Dave"=>50}}
```

Would that not be more convenient?